# automating microsoft ad user creation using powershell in cloudforamtion userdata

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am been working on Microsoft active directory for creating users using powershell commands or scripts which i want to include in cloudforamtion userdata or by ssm runpowershellscript command.
i want to remotely login into Active directory so i specified user credentials for login and execute powershell command for creating user with specified user details.
i am not able to know what is the problem, so here is the code:

```
[string][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $userPassword = "Dummypassword"
$username = "User@domain.example.com"
$userPassword = "ConvertTo-SecureString -String $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force"
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList  $username, $userPassword
$GivenName = "Mallikarjun"
$Surname = "kamble"
$User = $GivenName+"."+$Surname
$UPN = $User+"@adarsh.example.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Mallikarjun123" -AsPlainText -Force
New-ADUser -Credential $creds -Name $User -SamAccountName $User -UserPrincipalName $UPN - 
AccountPassword $Password -GivenName $GivenName -Surname $Surname -Enabled $True
```

if I execute it manually the error I am getting is:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:10
+ $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Argume ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

if there is any solution please let me know
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. I added code formatting to your error (by prepending 4 spaces on each line).

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"ConvertTo-SecureString -String $userPassword -AsPlainText -Force"`.